Auto number cells when entry made in corresponding cells
I want to autofill a number in "C4:ALN4" when "C5:ALN5" is filled with a text or value.
Before that I used a formula
=IF(C5\<\>"",COUNTA($C$5:C5),"")

Can a formula be converted to VBA code, and how?

You have several options.
You could just write the formula to the cells using VBA:
Range("C4:ALN4").Formula = "=IF(C5<>"""",COUNTA($C$5:C5),"""")"

If you want the formulas removed afterwards, you could:
With Range("C4:ALN4")
    .Formula = "=IF(C5<>"""",COUNTA($C$5:C5),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Or if you don't like the formulas and maybe want to do other things as part of the process, you could recreate the effect using code:
Dim cnt As Long, cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("C4:ALN4")
    If cel.Offset(1) = "" Then
        cel.Value = ""
    Else
        cnt = cnt + 1
        cel.Value = cnt
    End If
Next


You can use the following code:
With ActiveSheet.Range("C4:ALN4")
    .Formula = "=IF(C5<>"""",COUNTA($C$5:C5),"""")"
End With

Your formula is applied to the range you specify

Formulas can be used in VBA with Application.WorksheetFunction. However, it is usually easier to use VBA directly. For example  the IF-statement would be more tedious, just use the VBA if instead. The COUNTA-statement could be written as Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("...")). The value in the range is dependent on how you plan to call the VBA function, can be by button or the Worksheet.Change-Event, manually, etc.

Assuming that the data in row 5 are constants and not the results of formulas, you can use the following solution without loops:
Sub FillWithSeries()
    Range("C5:ALN5").Find("*", Range("ALN5")).Offset(-1).Value = 1
    Range("C5:ALN5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) _
        .Offset(-1).DataSeries , xlDataSeriesLinear
End Sub


Populate Count If Not Empty

When a cell contains an error value, your formula shows the same error value (green cells) instead of the count but continues COUNTA-ing correctly (pink cell). The same goes for cells containing Nothing (it shows Nothing, green cell). Also, all the resulting cells will not be blank (empty (in VBA terms)) i.e. =ISBLANK(C4:ALN4) (IsEmpty(Range("C4:ALN4")) in VBA terms) will return 0 (due to each cell containing a formula).



I could have mimicked this exact behavior (I mean minus the formula) but instead opted to show the count when a cell contains an error value and leave the empty cells empty (blank cells blank (in Excel terms)) i.e. =ISBLANK(C4:ALN4) (IsEmpty(Range("C4:ALN4")) in VBA terms) will be greater than 0 if there are any non-empty (non-blank (in Excel terms)) cells in the source range (C5:ALN5).
In the screenshot...

the red cells are empty (blank (in Excel terms),
the blue cell (L5) is not empty, it contains Nothing (in Excel terms)); in this particular case, it contains the formula ="" and BTW is also counted by COUNTA.




Sub PopulateCountIfNotEmpty()
    
    Const SRC_SINGLE_ROW_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "C5:ALN5"
    Const DST_ROW As Long = 4
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim Data() As Variant, c As Long, Count As Long
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_SINGLE_ROW_RANGE_ADDRESS)
        Data = .Value ' assumes more than one cell
        For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
            If Not IsEmpty(Data(1, c)) Then
                Count = Count + 1
                Data(1, c) = Count
            End If
        Next c
        .EntireColumn.Rows(DST_ROW).Value = Data
    End With

End Sub


Record a macro as you do the following
Highlight the range you want the formula to be in
paste your formula into the formula bar N.B. this is essential - do not paste the formula into a cell
Hit Ctrl-Enter. N.B. if you just hit Enter this will not work
Stop the macro recording and examine the code for Macro1 in Module1
However, I can't see how that formula ever worked with how you have described the problem - so make sure you get that working first, and take care with the row numbers - shouldn't that be C4 not C5 for example

Sorry, I edited my post, it's not D4:ALN4 but C5:ALN5.
